# CMAKE_MODULE_PATH .. CMAKE did not find REQUIRED package

Tags: ros2

I'm following ROS2 tutorial 'Using colcon to build packages'

> OS : Raspberry Pi
>
> Connection : ssh remote access
>
> ros2 humble is installed using docker

In Ubuntu laptop, I installed ros2 debian packages and I don't get CMake Errors

Error when I do `sudo colcon build --symlink-install` in Raspberry Pi

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findexample_interfaces.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "example_interfaces", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "example_interfaces" with any of the following names:

    example_interfacesConfig.cmake
    example_interfaces-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "example_interfaces" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "example_interfaces_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "example_interfaces" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

some answers say that i should `source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash`
[image]

but I got same error after sourcing

I tried to gain root access but gets me same error

[image]

Question.: where can I change CMAKE_MODULE_PATH myself?

I don't know why but using `sudo colcon build` makes the error.

use `colcon build` instead.

Comment: Can you please copy/paste (in a `code block`) the CMakeLists.txt file? What is the path to `Findexample_interfaces`? You can change the `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` with a command like `set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH /mypath)` in your CMakeLists.txt file, but it's not clear if that's really what you want or not. It could also be that you've got a line like the above that's overriding your `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` instead of *appending* to that path.